# Is there a way to rewrite the if statements to avoid repeating those 2 lines of code?

Tags: python, if-statement

I wrote insertion_sort function and added an if statement to choose if I want to order de array in ascendent or descendent mode. As you can see in the following code inside the if statements there are 2 lines of code repeated. I would like to know if there is another way to write those ifs so there´s no line repeated. I´ve been thinking about it but I can't think of any alternative.

Thanks in advance.

```
def swap_elements(array, pos1, pos2):
    array[pos1], array[pos2] = array[pos2], array[pos1]
    return array

def insertion_sort(array, method):
    i = 1
    while i < len(array):
        key = array[i]
        j = 0
        while j < i:
            if method:
                if array[j] > key:
                    key = array[j]
                    array = swap_elements(array, i, j)
            else:
                if array[j] < key:
                    key = array[j]
                    array = swap_elements(array, i, j)
            j += 1
        i += 1

    return array
```

Comment: `if (method and array[j] > key) or (not method and array[j] < key):`

Comment: Or `if array[j] > key if method else array[j] < key`

Comment: Also, note that both methods modify the array in-place, so returning it is not really necessary, and might be misleading.

Comment: That´s it! Thank you very much! I was making it more complicated than it really was.

Answer (score 0):

Latest version of the code:

```
def swap_elements(array, pos1, pos2):
    array[pos1], array[pos2] = array[pos2], array[pos1]

def insertion_sort(array, method):
    for i in range(len(array)):
        key = array[i]
        for j in range(i):
            if (method and array[j] > key) or (not method and array[j] < key):
                key = array[j]
                swap_elements(array, i, j)
```

Comment: You can also lose the `i`/`j` declarations and `+= 1` increments if you use `for i in range(1, len(array))` and `for j in range(i)` instead of the `while` loops.

Comment: @LTJ Yes, it´s true. Thanks! Losing those variables makes the code more readable.